# SCIP - Objective value can't be retrieved

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, scip

I have implemented benders decomposition in PySCIPopt using a constraint handler. In the constraint handler, I  use `model.getSolVal(sol, var)` to get the value of `var` in the master problem, which is used to add cuts after solving the subproblems. To get the objective value of the subproblem, I call `subproblem.getObjVal()`. This is running into this error for some instances:

```
Warning: getSolObjVal cannot only be called in stage SOLVING without a valid solution (current stage: 10)
```

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Edit: First, I solve the subproblem by calling `subproblem.optimize()`. Then I query the model for it's objective value using `subproblem.getObjVal()`. Note that subproblem is an object of the Model class in Pyscipopt. I don't understand why the problem is not in the solved stage (stage 10) after calling `subproblem.optimize()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the stage before calling it

```
if model.getStage() == 10:
    model.getSolObjVal()
```

BTW, the description says that you want to call `getObjVal()` where, it seems that, you're actually calling `getSolObjVal()`

[`SCIP_STAGE`](https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/type__set_8h.php#ac8ea6cabb843c57e1232f3132959e197) is an enum (you can use it as a reference to stage checking)

Comment: But why is the problem not getting solved after calling model.optimize?

Comment: could you please add more details to the question body explaining that problem?